# Public key ssh login from windows

Tags: ssh

My client provided me public key and asked me to do a ssh login. But i havent done any ssh login before. So can you please suggest me how to use public key for ssh login. I am using putty on windows

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very nice tutorial on how to setup key based authentication usint putty on Windows.
http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/pka-putty.html

Answer (score 0):

With SSH, public key is stored on the server and a user must have corresponding private key to log in. If this is your situation, you can specify your private key with PuTTY in one of two ways:

1. Configuration -> Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Private key file for authentication
2. Use `-i` command-line option when starting PuTTY.

In both cases you need the private key in PuTTY format (.ppk). If your key is in a different format, you'll have to convert it using PuttyGen.